# How to migrate GCP instances to AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, migration

I'm trying to migrate GCP instances to AWS, I have been searching for the solution but didn't find any references. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: What exactly do _you_ mean by "migrate GCP instances"? You probably don't want to migrate the whole contents of disk images (or do you?). Do you have scripts that can reinstall your software and other configurations? What have you got installed? Which OS? Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Hi John, as you mentioned it is not realistic to move an instance from GCP GCE to AWS EC2. There are too many low level scripts that interface with GCE metadata. Add the low level scripts required for AWS metadata. Then the processes involved at startup, device drivers, user creation / managment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS are customized differently in different cloud, so you can only migrate files and applications, by using Cloud Storage or AWS S3 as the bridge to migration files

While for the applications, you're recommended to build from scratch, but it highly depends on what exactly you want to migrate